# Rails 3 and saving decimal values from a form

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have an odd bug in one of my applications.

When I am using the sqlite3 database the bug is not present. However when I use mysql2 as the database adapter I run into an error saving decimal values from a form.

If I submit the value 19.99 my input after the decimal is removed and it is stored in the database as 19.00

What would cause this? The database has the correct settings for the column and I can create a correct record using the rails console.

Edit: Said integer when I really wanted to say decimal.

Comment: Is the value being saved correctly in the mysql table?

Comment: Nope, it gets submitted to mysql correctly as far as I can see from the rails logs. I am going to see if I can edit my migrations again with sscirrus's solution in mind and make sure everything is correct.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think it could be one of these possibilities:

1. A validation in your Rails model (or some step in your controller) is setting the value to an integer, or at least truncating the decimals, before saving to the database. To see if this is the case, check your `INSERT` operation in your logs and see what data Rails is *trying* to put in.
2. If Rails is sending `19.99` instead of `19.00`, you most likely have a small discrepancy between data types in your two databases. Check to see if your MySQL database is simply not storing the decimal **with a scale of 2 or higher**. MySQL by default stores data types with a precision of 10 and a scale of 0, thereby NOT storing decimals.

If #2 is the problem, the solution is to generate a migration and 'change' your field type to specify a scale, something like:

```
# 'up' portion of a new migration
def self.up
  change_column :mymodel, :myfield, :decimal, :precision => 6, :scale => 2
end
```

Comment: Thanks! You saved me from tearing my hair out over this. I must have had a typo in my migration or just not have checked something as throughly as I should have. The solution was to add :precision => 6, :scale => 2 to the end of the column definition in my migrations.

Comment: If you have a bunch of columns to change in the same table, you might also like this other syntax: change_table :mymodel do |t| t.change :myfield, :decimal, :precision => 6, :scale => 2